# PIP Python Installation weird error

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install PIP for Python3, but no matter what I try at some point I always end up with:

**E: Sub-pricess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)**

**E: Failed to process build dependencies.**

I tried with :

- **python get-pip.py** from the official PIP page.
- **sudo apt-get install python3-pip**
- **sudo apt-get build-dep python3.4**

I have the version of PIP for python2.7, so that's why I ran the latest command. Can someone help me out please ?

Comment: [More context, please.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139587/8412)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info /var/lib/dpkg/info.bak
2. sudo mkdir /var/lib/dpkg/info
3. sudo apt-get update

Hope it can help you(and others).